# Coupling & Design Patterns in Web vs Desktop Applications

Tags: web, structure, desktop-application, decoupling

I'm primarily a desktop application developer but I've been doing some web design projects recently and realized that I was doing significantly more switching between files while getting significantly less work done.

**Problem:**

When developing desktop applications, my favorite part is determining the best design patterns and data structures to use in order to minimize coupling and maximize cohesion. However, with web design, I seem to be all over the place in terms of structure. The large number of required scripting/programming languages has a lot to do with it. Even though I understand them, sometimes it is mentally exhausting getting them to work together perfectly. In just one project, you might use HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, SQL, XML, C#/VB, etc. Then, each has an arbitrary number of files and making a single change in one might require changes in numerous other files. In a world of abstraction, I would think that the whole process would be made much more concise and uniform.

**Questions:**

I typically use a MVC design so that I can design the view, link all of the triggers to the controller, and work on the controller/model without ever having to touch the view again. Is there a way to simulate this in web design? How well do design pattern from desktop applications port to web applications? Is there a way just to reduce the coupling feeling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I typically use a MVC design so that I can design the view, link all of the triggers to the controller, and work on the controller/model without ever having to touch the view again. Is there a way to simulate this in web design?

Use event attributes to simulate this:

```
<div class="view" onclick="controller('click')" onblur="controller('blur')" onload="controller('load')" onunload="controller('unload')" onerror="controller('error')">
</div>
```

> Is there a way just to reduce the coupling feeling?

Use different languages for each level, such as:

- XML for the Model, XSLT for the View, CSS for the Controller
- JSON for the Model, JSON.parse for the View, AJAX for the Controller
- CSV for the Model, FTP for the View, Socket for the Controller
- Logfile for the Model, SVG for the View, Perl for the Controller
- SQLite for the Model, CSV for the View, Spreadsheet for the Controller
- hTurtle for the Model, GRDDL for the View, jQuery for the Controller
- Gateway for the Model, PubSub for the View, Proxy for the Controller
- Metadata for the Model, Metaobjects for the View, Metacharacters for the Controller
- Dictionary for the Model, Hashed Array Tree for the View, Dispatch Table for the Controller
- Cache for the Model, Template for the View, Filters for the Controller
- URLs for the Model, URITemplates for the View, URITemplate Parser for the Controller
- Recordset for the Model, Heredoc for the View, Higher Order Functions for the Controller
- indexedDB for the Model, HTML for the View, JSON.stringify for the Controller
- HTML for the Model, CSS for the View, CSSOM for the Controller
- data:URIs for the Model, HTML for the View, CSS for the Controller
- XML for the Model, SVG for the View, SMIL Animation for the Controller
- URLs for the Model, Request Body for the View, Request Headers for the Controller

**References**

- [Reusable XSL Stylesheets and Templates - Tony Marston](http://www.tonymarston.net/xml-xsl/reusable-xsl.html)
- [The hTurtle Microformat](http://inamidst.com/sw/hturtle/)
- [CSS 2.1:Precedence of non-CSS presentational hints](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#preshint)
- [XHTML Flavors comparisons](http://www.w3.org/2007/09/dtd-comparison.html)
- [oneBox](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/oneBox.html)
- [SMIL: Challenges](https://wiki.mozilla.org/SMIL:Challenges)
- [Microsoft Application Architecture Guide, Chapter 8: Data Layer Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658127.aspx)
- [RIA Services - Enterprise Patterns with WCF RIA Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336308.aspx)
- [Hashed Array Tree Diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/HashedArrayTree16.svg)
- [HTTP: The Request](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Request.html)
- [URL Session Programming Guide: About the URL Loading System](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html)
- [C#, Web API: HTTP GET with a Request Body](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/849034/Csharp-Web-API-HTTP-GET-with-a-Request-Body)
- [JMESPath: A query language for JSON](http://jmespath.org/)
- [Encoding Dublin Core Metadata in HTML](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2731.txt)
- [DBI recipes](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=284436)
- [Ots Labs: Ots Media Query Language (OMQL) Documentation](http://www.otslabs.com/omql-docs/)
- [What is the difference between the Data Mapper, Table Data Gateway (Gateway), Data Access Object (DAO) and Repository patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804751/1113772)
- [Javascript: Using reviver function, I seem can't get to alter all the keys, while concating the numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435711/1113772)
- [Eliminate duplicates in array (JSONiq)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618767/1113772)
- [rendering tree view from json callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273772/1113772)
- [How to parse or query complex JSON in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326405/1113772)
- [Parse a json file with nested indexes and save as csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902466/1113772)
- [Adding value to JSON child array dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995037/1113772)
- [how to get companies id from linkedin jsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108544/1113772)
- [How to translate XML to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209157/1113772)
- [What are the differences between using JSON arrays vs JSON objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288820/1113772)
- [Advice for multi level csv file creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710122/1113772)